# String value not rendered in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, highcharts

I implemented the graph using high chart js, My service class returning an object which contains the graphical data, one of the property return the month and year like "December 2018", or "December,2018", but high-chart throws an error after render it and displays "December" is not declared and for "2018" unexpected token.

My question is how do I show the month name in the format, like "December 2018", it looks weird in the graph, currently  i am using default value that is 201812

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                            $('#container').highcharts({
                            chart: {
                            type: 'column'
                            },
                                    title: {
                                    text: 'Monthly Salary Statistics'

                                    xAxis: {
                                    categories: [${boardData.attDashboardData.valueBean.val1}],
                                            crosshair: true
                                    },
                                    yAxis: {
                                    min: 0,
                                            title: {
                                            text: 'Amount (INR)'
                                            }
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} INR</b></td></tr>',
                                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                                            shared: true,
                                            useHTML: true
                                    },
                                    plotOptions: {
                                    column: {
                                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                                            borderWidth: 0
                                    }
                                    },
                                    series: [{
                                    name: 'Gross Earning',
                                            data: [${boardData.attDashboardData.valueBean.val3} ]

                                    }, {
                                    name: 'Gross Deduction',
                                            data: [${boardData.attDashboardData.valueBean.val2}]

                                    }, {
                                    name: 'Net Pay',
                                            data: [${boardData.attDashboardData.valueBean.val4}]

                                    }]
                            });

    });

                        </script>

                        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I think highchart is not able to understand the string value inside the data[], please help me

[image]

SERVICE CLASS

```
 public TwoValueBeanVer2 getMothlySalaryStatistics(final String yearMonth, final String refId) {
        TwoValueBeanVer2 bean = new TwoValueBeanVer2();
        String query = "        SELECT "
                + "            YEAR_MONTH yearMonth, "
                + "            count(distinct EMPLOYEE_ID) tot_emp, "
                + "            SUM(net_salary) net_salary, "
                + "            SUM(gross_earning) gross_earn, "
                + "            SUM(gross_deduction) gros_deduct "
                + "            "
                + "        FROM "
                + "            employee_salary_summary "
                + "        WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN (1,2)  "
                + " AND REFERENCE_ID =" + refId
                + " AND YEAR_MONTH=" + yearMonth
                + " group by YEAR_MONTH ";

        List<AttOfficerDashboardDTO> list = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(query, new RowMapper<AttOfficerDashboardDTO>() {

            @Override
            public AttOfficerDashboardDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
                AttOfficerDashboardDTO dto = new AttOfficerDashboardDTO();
                dto.setTotEmp(rs.getInt("tot_emp"));
                dto.setGrossEarning(rs.getDouble("gross_earn"));
                dto.setGrossDeduction(rs.getDouble("gros_deduct"));
                dto.setGrossDeduction(rs.getDouble("gros_deduct"));
                dto.setNetPay(rs.getDouble("net_salary"));
                dto.setYearMonth(rs.getString("yearMonth"));
                return dto;
            }
        });
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            List<String> val1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> val2 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> val3 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> val4 = new ArrayList<>();

            for (AttOfficerDashboardDTO graphData : list) {
                val1.add(graphData.getYearMonth());
                val2.add(String.valueOf(graphData.getGrossDeduction()));
                val3.add(String.valueOf(graphData.getGrossEarning()));
                val4.add(String.valueOf(graphData.getNetPay()));
            }
            bean.setVal1(StringProcessorUtil.arrayToString(val1.toArray(new String[]{}), null));
            bean.setVal2(StringProcessorUtil.arrayToString(val2.toArray(new String[]{}), null));
            bean.setVal3(StringProcessorUtil.arrayToString(val3.toArray(new String[]{}), null));
            bean.setVal4(StringProcessorUtil.arrayToString(val4.toArray(new String[]{}), null));

        }
        return bean;

    }
}
```

[image]

My DOMAIN CLASS Generate the String vlaue of corresponding `monthYear`

```
public void setYearMonth(String yearMonth) {
        this.yearMonth = yearMonth;
        if (yearMonth != null) {
            String year = yearMonth.substring(0, 4);
            String month = yearMonth.substring(4, 6);
            monthYearStr = DateUtility.getMonthNameV2(month) + "," + year;
        }
    }
```

And The getMonthNAmeV2() method

```
 public static String getMonthNameV2(String month) {
        String m = "";
        switch (month) {
            case "01":
                m = "January";
                break;
            case "02":
                m = "February";
                break;
            case "03":
                m = "March";
                break;
            case "04":
                m = "April";
                break;
            case "05":
                m = "May";
                break;
            case "06":
                m = "June";
                break;
            case "07":
                m = "July";
                break;
            case "08":
                m = "August";
                break;
            case "09":
                m = "September";
                break;
            case "10":
                m = "October";
                break;
            case "11":
                m = "November";
                break;
            case "12":
                m = "December";
                break;
            default:
                m = "Invalid Month";
                break;
        }
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: see my edits plss

Comment: all the values showing in the graph

Comment: code is also included

Comment: see the image in my edits

Comment: see my edits you will get clear clarity about how the string is obtained

Comment: common suggest me the solution, i posted all the possible and helpful snippets